# View is spitting out strange data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have never seen this problem before in codeigniter.

I have a simple controller:

```
public function port($table) {

error_reporting(1);

$data['table_name'] = $table;



$data['am_data'] = $this->Charts_model->sp_vs_basic_portfolio($data);
$data['fuck'] = $this->Charts_model->get_ajax_portfolio_data($data);

$data['first_portfolio'] = $table;
$data['second_portfolio'] = $table . ' with Hardline';

$data['monthly'] = $this->Charts_model->get_portfolio_monthly_returns($data);
$data['annual'] = $this->Charts_model->get_portfolio_annual_returns($data);
$data['pieChart'] = $this->Charts_model->build_pieChart($data);

var_dump($data);
die;

$this->load->view('portfolio_new/portfolio_new_view', $data);
}
```

So you can see in the controller, I dump all my data and then die; This is working just fine. All the data I wanted is there. So when I go to the view, I get a bunch of: `�+��N���.NIKR)�i��U3`

So I made a simple view with no variables `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>` and I get a similar result. I have other views and controllers that working just fine on my site.

portfolio_new_view.php =

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

Comment: Please post your view too.

Comment: What kind of text editor are you using?  Sounds like a bunch of invisible characters in the file.  I seriously doubt this has anything to do with CodeIgniter... especially since some views are already working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might have your code editor saving in ANSI. I hope the code was not edited in Notepad and saved. That happens somethings since the default Encoding is ANSI.

Another possibility could be it was moved from another PC/OS

Add to your view file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Update the part of your config.php

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

And also set your editor to save files as UTF-8 ?

If it's none of the above and you already have UTF-8 set everywhere, you might want to create a new view file or test on code on another machine.

Comment: Good advice, but it doesn't really explain where those random characters are coming from.

Comment: Answer updated with more info on what might have caused this. I've experienced it in the past and that was my approach to solving it